# Test if browser supports unmuted playsinline video

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, html5-video

How can I test whether a video playsinline without being muted?

I've attempted this myself by creating a small piece of script that autoplays a tiny video (20kb). A boolean is returned based on whether the video is 'playing'.

It seems to be working. On iOS, it returns false. On desktop it returns true.

However, I wanted to get a second opinion whether this is the correct way to be running the test.

JS:

```
var $video = $('video');

$video.on( 'loadstart', function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    alert( isUnmutedInlineSupported() ? 'supported' : 'unsupported' );
  }, 500);
});

function isUnmutedInlineSupported(){
  if( !$video[0].paused && $video[0].currentTime > 0 ) {
    //playsinline unmuted supported
    return true;
  } else {
    //playsinline unmuted unsupported
    return false;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<video playsinline loop autoplay poster="https://placehold.it/1600x900">
  <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/214327/html5-video-sound-test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

https://codepen.io/hassforshort/pen/baXrXo

Comment: Yes, that should work. But what if your video won't start playing in 500ms? Probably to add some additional checks?

Comment: @AntonMalyshev I agree. It feels wrong/unnecessary, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to check if video has started or not. Recomended by webkit at https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/

```js
var promise = document.querySelector('video').play();

if (promise !== undefined) {
    promise.catch(error => {
        // Auto-play was prevented
        // Show a Play Button to let the user manually start playback
    }).then(() => {
        // Auto-play started
    });
}
```

You code might work on some desktop browser but it will not work on mobile. Different device has different support for video and only few supports autoplay video with sound.

Comment: This doesn't work. iOS Safari always returns true. See here: https://codepen.io/hassforshort/pen/mpNxoo

Comment: Problem is with uploaded video, please check https://codepen.io/tusharv/pen/aEeKZe here I have forked your codepen and updated video path.